# Infinite creation of node js app without any changes

Tags: node.js, fs

Here, I am just making the directory and writing a file inside that directory. And when I save it `nodemon app.js` gets automatically called and it goes to an infinite loop. 
Although I donot change anything in the code.

```
fs.mkdir("asyncFile",()=>{
    console.log("File Created");
});
fs.writeFile("asyncFile/hey.js","",()=> {
    console.log("async.js created");
});
console.log("And thats the end baby");
```

**output**

```
And thats the end baby
File Created
async.js created
```

But here is the thing. When I manually run `node app.js` it gets called time that's it.
 I am new to node.js please help me to understand this process.

Comment: You're changing files in the directory, which is telling nodemon to restart.

Comment: What is your `nodemon` command?  Are you telling it which files to watch/exclude?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat aren't we supposed to make changes inside the directory? Where else do we make changes?

Comment: @zero298 my nodemon command is `nodemon app.js` and inside app.js it is simply making a directory and writing a file inside it

Comment: You can add a nodemon.json file and ignore the asyncFile directory.  Use this in your nodemon.json file: `{ "ignore": ["asyncFile/*"] }`

Comment: umm dont write into your project source folder, it should be outside it, this why the standard is to have `src/` for source files and `data/` for data `logs/` for logs etc you wouldn't be writing scripts in a real script nor running nodemon in production

Comment: can anybody help me with, how do we generally create the node.js project. The directory and all that. So that I can make my project clean and errorless and easy. Any image or link or article might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Nodemon watch the project folder and when changes occour it rerun your application. When you save your changes nodemon restart the node, when restarted write on the file again, and nodemon starts again on node, so.... There's the loop!

Set the below line in your `package.json` file inside "scripts" section:

```
"dev": "nodemon --ignore './asyncFile/' ./app.js"
```

After that just run your project with `npm run dev`

> I used "dev" as keyword to execution, but you can set any word you want.

Comment: OK, that's a diagnosis, but don't you think an answer should also include the fix?

Comment: Ok, i will set it!